# Play framework module - eclipse development environment setup

Tags: java, eclipse, frameworks, playframework

I have developed a module using Play Framework. This module is used by multiple Play framework projects. Each time I change any code in the module I need to build the module and deploy it inside my other main applications. I do not want to do this step while doing the development in Eclipse. I only want to build the module when deploying in server. Is there any way my which I can achieve this - I do code change in module in eclipse all projects using this module automatically get the changes.

Thank you

Comment: How do you build your project? With Maven you could set a dependency to the local snapshot version instead of the latest released version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's play 1.2 you can declare your module to be loaded from local repository:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/dependency#repositories (section "Local repositories").

Play should then compile your module and always load latest sources when you start your app.
You might have issues if your modules use some jar deployed classes (not in app directory), then you would need to execute `play build-module`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marek.

Just to add, you need to do "Play eclipsify" to add the module project in the main projects source path.